# CruiseControl.Net intermittently detecting SVN modifications

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I am using ccnet 1.6. My build server and svn server clocks are synced pretty close (less than 30 second disparity). My ccnet config file has the correct settings to poll for SVN modifications as follows:

```
   <triggers>
            <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="30" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" initialSeconds="30"/>
        </triggers>

<sourceControlProvider type="svn" autoGetSource="true">
                <trunkUrl>xxx</trunkUrl>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client\svn.exe</executable>
                <username>brian</username>
                <password>xxx</password>
                <cleanCopy>true</cleanCopy>
            </sourceControlProvider>
```

When I commit anything, the build is triggered, I am brian, the username provided for the sourceControlProvider. A fellow team member does a commit and the build is triggered intermittently for him. Perhaps it is triggered intermittently for me too but I always seem to luck out and trigger the build when I commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the revision number to detect changes instead of the timestamp.

This can be enabed using the "revisionNumbers" property.

Check the docs at: http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Subversion_(svn)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a great solution, I will mark this as the answer in a day or two of monitoring my team member's commits to make sure they trigger the ccnet build